# Break in switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm coding a little tic tac toe game in java and I'm adding a functionnnality that asking if the player wants to continue to play or not.
The problem is that in my switch, the break is not understood and don't break the program when we say that we want to stop.
Can someone help me find the problem in my code ?
Thanks !

```
System.out.println("Do you want to continue ? (yes/no) ?");
            String playAgain = scanner.nextLine();

            switch (playAgain) {

                case "yes":
                    System.out.println("let's continue");

                case "no":
                    System.out.println("Bye");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Please enter a right instruction");

            }
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a break in your "yes" case.

Comment: "the break is not understood and don't break the program when we say that we want to stop. " <- Because that is not what a break statement in a switch case does at all: [Another point of interest is the break statement. Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). A break inside a switch case does not break the whole program flow or terminate the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not the way the `break` keyword works. It ends the `switch` statement, not the program.

In your code, if the option is `yes`, both `yes` and `no` codes will be executed because there is no `break` before the `no`.

You probably want something like that:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to continue ? (yes/no) ?");

String playAgain = scanner.nextLine();

switch (playAgain) {
case "yes":
  System.out.println("let's continue");
  break;

case "no":
  System.out.println("Bye");
  System.exit();

default:
  System.out.println("Please enter a right instruction");
  // You will need some control loop to make it work... 
}
```